# How to combine SoapUI, Maven and HermesJMS with Jenkins build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, soap, soapui, hermes-jms

My soap project with HermesJMS works perfectly when run from SoapUI, Command Line (mvn test). 
However, it fails when the same project is run on Jenkins. I get the below error on the Jenkins console:

```
SoapUI 5.4.0 Maven2 TestCase Runner
2018-10-22 13:35:27,446 [main] INFO  
com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner - Setting global property [ENV] to [TEST]
 13:35:27,839 WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [../ext] for external libraries
 13:35:27,839 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/../soapui-settings.xml]
 13:35:29,217 INFO  [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 25 ms
 13:35:29,217 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
 13:35:30,718 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:../..soapui-project.xml]
 13:35:30,728 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI tests in project 
 13:35:30,729 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running Project runType = SEQUENTIAL
 13:35:30,746 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [TestCase 1]
 13:35:30,782 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [SOAP Request]
 HermesJMS Home must be set in global preferences
 13:35:30,833 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [HermesJMS home not specified !!!], see error log for details
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: HermesJMS home not specified !!!
```

And below is my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <configuration> </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
                <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                <artifactId>doxia-site-renderer</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>hermesjms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hermes</artifactId>
                    <version>1.14</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>SoapUI Tests</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                <globalProperties>
                <value>ENV=TEST</value>
                </globalProperties>
                <projectFile>..soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                 <!--
                <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/SoapUI-Report</outputFolder> 
                -->
                <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                <printReport>true</printReport>
                <environment>DEV</environment>
                <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                <goal>report-only</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What am I missing in the pom.xml or do I need to update soapui-setting.xml with HermesJMS location in the jenkins server where it gets built?

Comment: According to your error **HermesJMS home not specified**. Is HermesJms installed on your Jenkins machine?

Comment: I need to check it out with respective department. As I don't have access to the server.What else needs to be taken care of in the jenkins server?

Comment: From a functional point, what does your maven + sopaui + hermesjs integration?